mat sort header not working with the column created
I'm facing difficulties implementing a date filter in a table using Angular Material. The dates are retrieved from an API in the format "YYYY-MM-DD", all the columns are working except the created
here is the code
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
displayedColumns: string[] = [
'id',
'Name',
'Description',
'Status',
'created',
'Actions',
];

getSales(): void {
this.sales_service.getSales().subscribe({
  next: (val) => {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(val);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  },
});
}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.getSales();}

Html:
<ng-container matColumnDef="created">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
      Created At
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      {{ element.createdAt | date }}
    </td>
</ng-container>

can anyone helpe me, pls

issue not reproducible stackblitz

Could you provide the data structure of the returned value for getSales()? Also, do you have a method defined for (matSortChange)? Or are you using "this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor"?
